# How to fetch device activity data using Family control framework, Individual, Swift UI, Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am using iOS 16  and try to fetch all of the applications daily screen duration time and name.
Does anyone facing with the same issue? or am I doing something wrong?

```
    let schedule = DeviceActivitySchedule(intervalStart: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0), intervalEnd: DateComponents(hour: 23, minute: 59), repeats: true, warningTime: nil)

    let center = DeviceActivityCenter()
    
    do {
        
        try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule)
        
        print(center.schedule(for: DeviceActivityName.init(rawValue: "Event")) as Any)
        
    }
    catch {
        
        print ("Could not start monitoring \(error)")
        
    }

    store.dateAndTime.requireAutomaticDateAndTime = true
    store.account.lockAccounts = true
    store.passcode.lockPasscode = true
    store.siri.denySiri = true
    store.appStore.denyInAppPurchases = true
    store.appStore.maximumRating = 200
    store.appStore.requirePasswordForPurchases = true
    store.media.denyExplicitContent = true
    store.gameCenter.denyMultiplayerGaming = true
    store.media.denyMusicService = false
}
```